# get textarea value from table HTML

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to get the data in the textarea which is in nested table. I use the row Index to get the data in that row.

I tried this , but it is not work.

```
var note = document.getElementById($index).cells[3];
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea").value;
```

Here is the table.

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, x) in records" id="{{$index}}">
    <td>{{key}}</td>
    <td>{{x.title}}</td>
    <td>{{x.year}}</textarea></td>
    <td>
         <textarea rows="2" cols="30">{{x.note}}</textarea>
         <button type="button" ng-click="update($index)">Update</button>
    </td>
    <td><button type="button" ng-click="delete($index)">Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that you also have the ending of a previous textarea control here, which might cause a problem for getElementsByTagName:

```
<td>{{x.year}}</textarea></td>
```

```js
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value;
alert(y);
```

```html
<tr>
        <td>17</td>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td>Year</td>
        <td>
             <textarea rows="2" cols="30">this is my note</textarea>
             <button type="button">Update</button>
        </td>
        <td><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe here is the error, you are closing a textarea:

```
<td>{{x.year}}</td>
```

After try with it:

```
var y = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].value;
```